# Derivation Of Rotational Energy From Kinetic Energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics

I am studying rotation, and I would like to check that my understanding
is correct. I am trying to prove that:

$$
\tau \theta = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2
$$

To prove this, let's consider an object that is constrained to rotate about an axis
with no translation of that axis. A force $F$ is applied tangentially at
a distance $r$ from the axis of rotation.

When the object has rotated through $\theta$ radians, the point of force
application has traveled a distance $d = r \theta$. Thus $Fd = F r
\theta$ work has been done.

We assume that all the work performed has been converted into kinetic
energy. Different parts of the object will be moving at different
velocities. We label the "parts" of the object with an index $i$. We
know:

$$
F r \theta = \sum_i \text{KE}_i = \sum_i \frac{1}{2} m_i v_i^2
$$

$m_i$ is the mass of part $i$, while $v_i$ is the velocity of part $i$. Because the object is constrained to rotate rigidly, we know $v_i$ must be directed tangentially, and that $v_i = r_i \omega_i$, where $r_i$ is the radial
distance of part $i$ from the axis of rotation, and $\omega_i$ is the
angular velocity. We further know that all $\omega_i$ are constant. Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
F r \theta &= \sum_i \frac{1}{2} m_i r_i^2 \omega^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_i m_i r_i^2 \right) \omega^2
\end{align}
$$

This motivates me to define new vocabulary: *torque* $\tau = Fr$ and
*rotational inertia* $I = \sum_i m_i r_i^2$. We know:

$$
\begin{align}
\tau \theta = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2
\end{align}
$$

Our derivation is complete. As far as I can tell, my assumptions were:

1. The object is constrained to undergo only rotation,
2. All work done by the force must be converted to kinetic energy of the objects' parts.

My argument appears to arrive at the correct conclusion. Is it valid?

Comment: *When the object has rotated through  radians, the point of force application has traveled a distance =. Thus = work has been done.* Work on what? If you mean the whole object, it has *not* traveled that distance.

Comment: It is right. But there is also other assumptions: $\tau$ is constant, and the object is rotating around one of the principal inertia axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, but can be extended to consider the net force (vector sum of all forces) acting on the body.  A couple of points.  (1) This holds for a rigid body: a system of particles whose mutual distances are all constant.  (2) If the object is undergoing translational motion, the rotation should be taken about the center of mass so that the total kinetic energy is that of translation of the center of mass plus rotation about the center of mass.

As you state, this relationship is for rotation about a fixed axis (or an axis through the center of mass that always has the same direction in space for additional translational motion.)  The relationships for general motion are more complicated involving the inertia tensor.  See Goldstein, Classical Mechanics.